# How to center background image on page?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble centering an image as a fullscreen background under a navbar. Here is the code I'm currently working with.

```css
header{
  background-image: url("design.jpg");
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `background-size: contain;` to `background-size: cover` and seeing what happens?

Answer (score -2):

The simple approach as similar to your code is

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

There are few other tricks as well, which you'll get from here

> https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Hope it helps.

-NBaua

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes